# Messaging center not calling from xamarin ios task

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app, I am trying to create background task and service in ios and android . I created service for android and task for ios. According to the service and task I am trying to call a web API in my shared code. I am communicating to my shared code using Messaging center. In android the communication works fine. But in ios the messaging center not subscribing in the shared code.

**My ios background Task**

```
 public class iOSLongRunningTaskExample
    {
        nint _taskId;
        CancellationTokenSource _cts;

        public async Task Start()
        {
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            _taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask("LongRunningTask", OnExpiration);

            try
            {

   // Here I am calling the shared code 

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), 
                    "CheckNotificationAPI")
                );

            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                //if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                //{
                //    var message = new CancelledMessage();
                //    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                //        () => MessagingCenter.Send(message, "CancelledMessage")
                //    );
                //}
            }

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(_taskId);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
        }

        void OnExpiration()
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

**My Shared code**

```
   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "CheckNotificationAPI", async (sender) =>
            {

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Message", "Recieved", "OK");
                });

            });
```

**My android service which works fine**

```
[Service]
public class LongRunningTaskService : Service
{
    CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task.Run(() => {
            try
            {
                //INVOKE THE SHARED CODE
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>
                MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), "CheckNotificationAPI")
                 );         
          }
            catch (System.OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                //if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                //{
                //    var message = new CancelledMessage();
                //    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                //        () => MessagingCenter.Send(message, "CancelledMessage")
                //    );
                //}
            }

        }, _cts.Token);

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (_cts != null)
        {
            _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            _cts.Cancel();
        }
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see you, using `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` in native code, Wouldn't it make more sense to use the native methods? Also why exactly are you using native classes to call an API? Wouldn't it make more sense to do it in shared code? Also, why are you using `MessagingCenter` for this? Shouldn't you have a direct reference for this which you could use?

Comment: @FreakyAli Bro. What I am trying to achieve is calling an API in shared code when task is called. So how to do that? I put api calling inside the subscribe portion of messaging center. but it didn't subscribed

Comment: try this i guess https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest

Comment: @AndroDevil Hi ,does code invoked in `iOSLongRunningTaskExample` ? First you should check whether `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` works in `iOSLongRunningTaskExample` . An d if just want to get data from api , using Restful as FreakyAli said is a good way to realize it.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I simply want to initialize messeging centre from iOSLongRunningTaskExample  and subscribe it on shared code

Comment: @AndroDevil Maybe there is something wrong with IOS backgroud Task . https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time?language=objc Why not using `Task` an `async/await` in Forms to realize this backgroud task. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#composition-with-tasks